# What is the meaning of "tomatazo"?

Tags: vocabulario, sustantivos, sufijos

To give a bit of context, in the line:

> *Recibió una lluvia de **tomatazos**.* ("He was pelted with tomatoes.")

The word *tomatazos* is used rather than *tomates*. What is the meaning of ***tomatazo***?

I've consulted dictionaries and SpanishDict and am no closer to an answer.

Comment: You've got two great answers but I just want to add, take anything and make it an instrument of hurt or destruction, and that makes it an "-azo."  For example, take the elbow.  Normally it just minds its own business.  Bump into someone with it, on purpose or by accident, and you can call that action a "codazo."  Also, take any piece of fruit, unripe, ripe, past its prime, or downright rotten, and throw it -- now you have "-azo."  If you dislike Stravinsky's latest ballet and throw tomato missiles at the dancers, you are hurling "tomatazos."

Answer (score 7):

The suffix *-azo* (or *-aza*) can be used to make sustantives with the meaning of "a hit given with (something)":

> [**-azo, za**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=-azo)
>
> 5. suf. A veces significa golpe dado con lo designado por la base derivativa. *Porrazo, almohadillazo*.

So, from *tomate* + *-azo* we get ***tomatazo***, meaning "**a hit given with a tomato**".

Your translation is replacing the suffix with its actual meaning. A more literal translation (though I like yours more) would be *"He received a rain of tomato hits"*.

Answer (score 6):

To add more information to [@walen's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24114/12637), I'd like to add that the RAE's Spanish Grammar contains [a whole chapter about the *-azo* suffix](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KMoTTvtpqWKcmOjd) (link in Spanish). It basically says that the *-azo* suffix comes from latin *-acĕus* and it forms a number of compounds in Spanish that refer to hits and sudden actions. So *cabezazo* means *a hit with (or in) the head*. The base word is usually a noun but it can also be a verb, as in *frenazo* (a sudden braking).

The producivity of this suffix is outstanding, as you can form compounds with almost every noun: *zapatazo* would mean *a hit with a shoe*, and not *a big shoe*. So the *Gramática* warns us that **due to the big amount of possible compounds it is not possible to register them all in the dictionary**.

The compound forms that refer to hits come mainly from weapons, instruments, utensils and physical objects in general: *banderillazo, barquinazo, bastonazo, batazo, botellazo, cabezazo, cachiporrazo, cantazo, cuentazo, culatazo, escobazo, fierrazo, filazo, garrotazo, ladrillazo, macanazo, machetazo, martillazo, palazo, palmetazo, pepazo, piquetazo, puyazo, quiñazo, rolazo, sartenazo, talegazo, tetuntazo, toletazo, trancazo, varetazo* and many more. You can also use parts of the body: *codazo, puñetazo, rodillazo, testarazo, zarpazo, derechazo, zurdazo*.

Please check the link above to get more information about the subject (quite interesting even for Spanish-language natives).